# Split By Image Tag

Tags: java, regex, string

I got stuck at once place for pattern matching string by "img" tag, please ignore my English ,Following is what i am doing:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<img[^>]*src=[\\\"']([^\\\"^']*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("whole text here with img tag including");
```

This is giving me all the img tag properly, but my concern is that i want only those img tags whose length is greater than 2000, means whole img tag with length more than 2000, and if it is less than it should not count it out, can it be possible with regex? And if yes than what changes do i need to do here in regex?

Comment: `Pattern.compile("(<img[^>]*src=[\\\"']([^\\\"']{2000,})");`

Comment: you mean the length of src attrib?

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj it solved my issue :)